# Asking questions about disabled travel and immigration

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I'm disabled, on wheelchair, I would like to ask 2 questions, one about visiting a country, another about immigrating. Is it okay or would they be closed as off topic?

It's about requirements and whether disabled get rejected and stuff like that.

Comment: I asked the same question on meta.expatriates.se, waiting for answers, checking the scope of both sites.

Comment: Did you see where someone was refused because they used a mobility aide?

Comment: @GayotFow yes many countries don't want disabled immigrants including the US because they dont want to pay for health services, although i won't cost them anything, i don't think people like me are accepted

Comment: Two questions then.  Visiting is ok in travel; migration goes in expats.

Comment: If your question about visiting is specific there is no reason why it does not belong here.

Comment: @GayotFow ok, will ask the immigration question coz it seems more complicated, and in few days will ask the travel question, thanks

Comment: Does this question need to have a formal answer?

Comment: I believe it deserves one, and yours sounds like the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question about visiting a country seems very much on topic here (though with more details it might be that some aspect falls foul of what is off topic here).

A question about immigrating is very likely off topic here, though may well not be (subject to the usual provisos) at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Disability or no might make a difference to the answers but should make absolutely no difference to on/off topic or where to ask, provided it is a subsidiary consideration to Travel or immigration.

However the above would seem all irrelevant as you don't appear to have asked either question on either site.